# How to place the Uid to a textview with acr122u?

Tags: android, acr122

I use the code below but it always crashes. I want the UID in textview data. Can anyone help me? I use the library from asc

```
reader.setOnStateChangeListener(new Reader.OnStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChange(int slotNum, int prevState, int currState) {
            //De APDU command om de UID uit te lezen
            byte[] command = {(byte)0xFF, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00};
            final byte[] response = new byte[256];

            if(currState == Reader.CARD_PRESENT) {
                try {
                    reader.power(slotNum, Reader.CARD_WARM_RESET);
                    reader.setProtocol(slotNum, Reader.PROTOCOL_T0 | Reader.PROTOCOL_T1);
                    reader.transmit(slotNum, command, command.length, response, response.length);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TextView data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LidkaartID_detail);
                            //data.append(Arrays.toString(response));
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Arrays.toString(response), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (ReaderException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you post the error ?

Comment: No because my usb ncf reader is plugged in. if i comment data.setText and the line with Toast then the app crashes not.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are trying to update the UI from a background thread. Use this :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.append(text);
    }
});
```

Comment: It helped me but the textview don't work. I try with a Toast end then it will work. I have updated my code.

Comment: I will my response into my TextView data. If i do that it will crash. That's why i comment the line data.append. At a toast it works. i have no logs because i work with a usb device (acr122) on a tablet so i can not debug.

Comment: You can connect your phone to Android Studio via adb network (in developer settings)